# Retrieve nested List in ReportDataSource using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, reporting-services

So here's my problem. I have a ms report(.rdlc) that uses a subreport. My data model is this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
        Orders = new List<CustomerOrder>();
    }

    public Customer(int id, string name, string address, string city, string state, IEnumerable<CustomerOrder> orders ):this(id)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Address = address;
        City = city;
        State = state;
        Orders.AddRange(orders);
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public List<CustomerOrder> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerOrder
{
    public CustomerOrder()
    {
    }

    public CustomerOrder(int id, string salesOrderNumber, string orderDate, string total)
    {
        Id = id;
        SalesOrderNumber = salesOrderNumber;
        OrderDate = orderDate;
        Total = total;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SalesOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string Total { get; set; }
}
```

There is an event to hook into for the subreport. It is used like this:

```
 LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();
```

...

```
 localReport.SubreportProcessing += localReport_SubreportProcessing;
```

...

```
 void localReport_SubreportProcessing(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
 {

    var mainSource = ((LocalReport)sender).DataSources["dsCustomers"];
    var subSource = ((List<Customer>)(mainSource.Value)).SelectMany(t => t.Orders).ToList();

    e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(SubReportDSName, subSource));

}
```

I'm trying to get the List back based on Id value. When I run this I get all Orders in list back for as many Customer ID's that exist. So this event gets hit four times if I have of course four customers in main report. So I need a way to filter the LIST using LINQ and not sure proper way to do it.  Here's a sample of the data.

```
    private List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
    private List<CustomerOrder> custOrders = new List<CustomerOrder>(); 

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public CustomersRepository()
    {

        try
        {
            custOrders.Add(new CustomerOrder { Id = 1, OrderDate = "12/14/2003", SalesOrderNumber = "SO59986", Total = "2372.95" });
            custOrders.Add(new CustomerOrder { Id = 1, OrderDate = "12/27/2003", SalesOrderNumber = "SO60850", Total = "2443.35" });
            custOrders.Add(new CustomerOrder { Id = 1, OrderDate = "04/08/2002", SalesOrderNumber = "SO45861", Total = "3578.27" });
            custOrders.Add(new CustomerOrder { Id = 1, OrderDate = "12/22/2003", SalesOrderNumber = "SO60561", Total = "2419.06" });

            customers.Add(new Customer(1, "Aaron Wright", "7024 rue Surcouf", "Bobigny", "Seine Saint Denis", custOrders));

            custOrders.Clear();

            custOrders.Add(new CustomerOrder { Id = 2, OrderDate = "08/08/2003", SalesOrderNumber = "SO52261", Total = "42.28" });
            custOrders.Add(new CustomerOrder { Id = 2, OrderDate = "12/19/2003", SalesOrderNumber = "SO60342", Total = "195.59" });
            custOrders.Add(new CustomerOrder { Id = 2, OrderDate = "02/15/2004", SalesOrderNumber = "SO64201", Total = "17.27" });
            custOrders.Add(new CustomerOrder { Id = 2, OrderDate = "06/19/2004", SalesOrderNumber = "SO73274", Total = "28.99" });

            customers.Add(new Customer(2, "Alexandria Bell", "8346 Niagara Court", "Langford", "British Columbia", custOrders));

            custOrders.Clear();

            custOrders.Add(new CustomerOrder { Id = 3, OrderDate = "12/13/2003", SalesOrderNumber = "SO59957", Total = "2319.99" });
            custOrders.Add(new CustomerOrder { Id = 3, OrderDate = "09/03/2002", SalesOrderNumber = "SO47472", Total = "2181.5625" });

            customers.Add(new Customer(3, "Alexandria Bell", "6275 Bel Air Drive", "Redmond", "Washington", custOrders));

            custOrders.Clear();

            custOrders.Add(new CustomerOrder { Id = 4, OrderDate = "03/19/2004", SalesOrderNumber = "SO66442", Total = "2354.98" });
            custOrders.Add(new CustomerOrder { Id = 4, OrderDate = "09/30/2001", SalesOrderNumber = "SO44271", Total = "3578.27" });

            customers.Add(new Customer(4, "Lisa Zheng", "8360 Frisbie Court", "Newcastle upon Tyne", "England", custOrders));
        }
```

I have tried to add an int Indx; inside the method being called up and using a where condition on:

```
var subSource = ((List<Customer>)(mainSource.Value)).SelectMany(t => t.Orders).ToList();
```

and then ++Indx but this fails miserably because Indx on second or third time around to method call is like 12 or 15 etc. So this must be due to threading with Microsoft report rendering engine.

Expected Output in Report:

Customer #1  Name, Address
--> Subreport:
    Order#1  OrderDate   SalesOrderNumber   Total
             OrderDate   SalesOrderNumber   Total

Customer #2  Name, Address
--> Subreport:
    Order#2  OrderDate   SalesOrderNumber   Total
             OrderDate   SalesOrderNumber   Total

Any ideas to properly extract only the List of Orders I need using LINQ would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks,
D

Ok so the main question is and its not report related but about LINQ. This statement gets me a generic list of CustomerOrders :

```
 var subSource = ((List<Customer>)(mainSource.Value)).SelectMany(t => t.Orders).ToList();
```

What is the proper where clause filter using linq to bring back a certain subset of this list?

Comment: What sense does it make to call `custOrders.Clear();` immediately after having added items to the list?

Comment: So I can only include a subset of CustomerOrders related to a certain customer ID. Notice where I add CustOrders collection to customers collection based on Customer Id?

Comment: Okay. You could simplify it by using array initializers: `new Customer(1, "...", "...", "...", "...", new CustomerOrder[] { new CustomerOrder { ... }, new CustomerOrder { ... }, new CustomerOrder { ... } })`